# Split-Half Reliability Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, preprocessing

I have a pandas dataframe of baseball stats that I have transposed that looks as follows:

[image]

Each column represents a separate plate appearance for a player. Each player can (and usually is) represented in many columns. Each row is an outcome for said plate appearance.

I'm trying to split each player's plate appearances into two equal portions (if `player_a` appears in 50 columns, I'd need two portions of 25).

How would I be able to run Cronbach's alpha (or Kuder-Richardson for binary events) for sets in each sample? My goal is to figure out the split-half reliability of each stat (row) in the data frame.

Is there a simpler way to do this that I'm not immediately seeing? I think I need to run some sort of for loop in Python to achieve my desired result, but it is currently escaping me.